# How does CI deployment to AWS typically work at scale?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-integration, production-environment

I am familiar with deploying a personal app to Heroku with `git push` and scaling it up by adding more dynos. But how do you deploy to a scaled AWS infrastructure with thousands of private instances behind dozens of load balancers across multiple regions?

I have searched and searched for this on Google and only found "hello world" tutorials describing cloning a repo directly to a single instance, or using CodeDeploy to deploy to a single instance, and then using autoscaling groups. Basically equivalent to my Heroku example.

But what does it actually look like in production systems at say Facebook, GitHub, Twitter, Stripe, or other large companies, if they were to run on AWS? Are they pushing to a single "global" bastion instance, and then it fans out to the rest of the private instances across multiple regions in one swoop? Or is some sort of *plan* (like a terraform plan) created, which needs manual approval, and then there's a custom deploy script which ssh's into the bastion instance and then fans out to each region? Or is it a git hook integrated into CI somehow?

What is typical of a large AWS deployment in terms of how you actually deploy your latest code changes to production, given you have thousands of instances across multiple availability zones and regions?

I am just wondering about a single service. I would imagine this process would be repeated per microservice or whatever. So for the sake of the question, imagine there is a single webserver with thousands of instances in every region. How would a deployment for that typically look? I am looking to create some GitHub actions to deploy to AWS as practice for a large project, but have no idea what the state of the art is, and haven't been able to find any information on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> imagine there is a single webserver with thousands of instances in every region. How would a deployment for that typically look?

Generally, you would create a AWS CodePipeline in one region with the [source stage having GithHub source action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html).

Depending on the project, this would be followed by a build stage, to compile the code, download extra dependencies or perform other operations needed. The build stage would be followed by testing stage for integration tests for example. Both can be performed using [CodeBuild actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html).

Once everything is fine, you could have [manual approval](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html) before performing the deployment to the servers.

For cross-region deployments, you could have [cross-region CodeDeploy actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html). The actions would perform the deployments to each instance in its respective region.

A good example of cross-region deployments is provided and explained in **AWS blog posts**:

- [Building a Cross-Region/Cross-Account Code Deployment Solution on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-a-cross-regioncross-account-code-deployment-solution-on-aws/)
- [Using AWS CodePipeline to Perform Multi-Region Deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codepipeline-to-perform-multi-region-deployments/)
- [Building a CI/CD pipeline for multi-region deployment with AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-multi-region-deployment-with-aws-codepipeline/)